# Setting character $ to wrap text as parentheses in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Suppose following code exists.

```
sample text
```

When user double click `text`, then press `{` or `(`, it just wraps the text while keeping it.

```
sample {text}
sample (text)
```

But I don't know how to apply this rule to `$` in VS Code Settings.
What I expect is

```
sample $text$
```

Which setting in VS Code is related to this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Edit> Auto Surround

is the setting in vscode.  But it only applies to quotes and brackets like `(), {}, <> and []` (and possibly some other language-defined cases).  You cannot change that setting to include another character like `$` unfortunately.

Here is a keybinding you might try (in keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+4",         // or whatever keybinding you wish
  "command":  "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    //  "snippet": "\\$$TM_SELECTED_TEXT\\$"

       // to have the text still selected after the $'s are inserted, use this
    "snippet": "\\$${1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\\$"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
```

So that any selected text will be wrapped by a `$` when you select it and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (where the `$` is on an English keyboard).  If you do that operation a lot it might be worth it.

If you use this line instead in the snippet above:

```
    "snippet": "$1$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$1"  // or

    "snippet": "$1${2:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}$1"
```

then more generically select text to surround, trigger that keybinding and type whichever and how many characters you want to wrap the selection.

Comment: It really helped. Thanks! BTW, it loses focus after the command, but there seems no option to keep the focus on selected text. Is there any related one?

Comment: I edited my answer so that the selected text remains selected after being wrapped.  On the second generic version remember to hit `tab` after you type the wrapping - then the original selected text will be selected again.