# VS Code : create custom snippet/shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I would like to have the following feature on VSCode and I don't know if it is possible. For example, if I have this line :

```
I would like to emphasize this.
```

I would just select `this`, clic on a shortcut like `ctrl+i` and then this appears :

```
I would like to emphasize {i}this{/i}.
```

I use a lot of `{i}` and `{/i}` tags in my project so this would help me save an incredible amount of time !

I know VSCode already does something similar when you select a word and clic on `"`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593920/setting-character-to-wrap-text-as-parentheses-in-vscode/60594017#60594017 for example, that answer wraps with a `$`.  If you need help modifying it to wrap with your tags let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Mark ! Works fine :) My question is in fact a duplicate but i couldn't find it as i didn't use the same words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find your `keybindings.json` file and insert the following snippet:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+i",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "{i}$TM_SELECTED_TEXT{/i}"
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
}
```

Key bindings can be found by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P > type "Keyboard shortcuts", full name being: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON).